# By rotating rig, the scale changes

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, transforms

I don't know, if this question was already answered but I have following problem.
I am trying to rotate a wheel at my bike and while changing the bone rotation the wheel changes the scaling, too. But I don't know why. I already applied and cleared all transform, on armature as well on mesh. And I also don't see any changement by scaling or other values, only the rotating value changes. Maybe someone could help me, I would really appreciate that.[image]

Comment: Probably the wheel also assigned to the root bone. You have to remove the wheel's verts from the root bone's vertex group.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think about that. The problem is solved :) Have a nice day.